# Stream multiple files on a single end point

Tags: php, xml, laravel, apache

I have multiple xml files stored on disk, like

```
file1.xml
file2.xml
```

I have another service that consumes these files but as a single file, like i have to merge them to a single file say for example, result.xml, which contains content from both files ( i have a scheduled job that parses these file parts to a single file)

My question is there any mechanism that i can stream these file parts as a single file to the consumer service?